# GWT Application shows blank page on IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-10

I've a web application developed using GWT. The application works fine with all the browsers except with IE10. It randomly shows up a black page when loading the application.

When I enable the network trace, I see the following entry which is causing the blank page appear.

```
/demo/04CD47D11F9ABA6EF09A5F41AA80D95C.cache.html   GET 404 text/html   
3.51 KB
```

What I see is when the blank page appears, in the network trace a call to cache.html fails with 404

Update:

The problem does not occur frequently. When it occurs the blank page would disappear if I clear complete browsing history, open a new tab then open the URL. This is kind of a workaround but annoying as a user of the application.

I looked at the GWT docs, but found no valid information. Any workaround is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you often recompile and redeploy the application?

Comment: No. The application is already deployed and running in production.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be caused by a cached `modulename.nocache.js`.

The GWT compiler will create some browser-specific files (Lets say: mozilla.js, webkit.js, ie10.js, ie9.js and ie8.js)

These files have some cryptic names (like the one, with the 404), but it easier to explain with simple names.

The compiled output looks like:

```
/app/app.html
/app/module.nocache.js
/app/module/mozilla.cache.js
/app/module/webkit.cache.js
/app/module/ie10.cache.js
/app/module/ie9.cache.js
/app/module/ie8.cache.js
```

The `app.html` loads the `module.nocache.js`
The `module.nocache.js` decides which browserspecific file (=permutation) has to be loaded.

Your error can only happen, if the `module.nocache.js` and the permutations are not from the same compile-process.

The most common cause is, that a browser caches the `*.nocache.js` Please ensure, that you have a filter, that sends no-cache header for files with the pattern `*nocache*`.

I don't know your webserver, for a tomcat, this can be done by adding a servlet-filter for a *nocache* pattern.

Comment: Valuable insights to the problem Christian. Yes the web server used is Tomcat. The problem is not repeated every time, it randomly crops up and gives a blank screen. On introspection, I see the HTML 404 error for the *cache.html